# Angular 4: Using ngIf and ngFor for the same field within ngFor

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4 and I am stuck in an issue in my code.
Below is my code:

JSON:

```
          [{"name": "A", "date": "2017-01-01", "value": "103.57"},
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-01-08", "value": "132.17"}, 
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-01-15", "value": "268.04"}, 
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-01-22", "value": "235.10"}, 
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-01-29", "value": "83.78"}, 
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-02-12", "value": "162.52"}, 
           {"name": "A", "date": "2017-02-19", "value": "131.63"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-01-01", "value": "0.56"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-01-08", "value": "275.55"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-01-15", "value": "288.37"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-01-29", "value": "250.05"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-02-05", "value": "124.90"}, 
           {"name": "B", "date": "2017-02-12", "value": "6.15"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-01-08", "value": "75.55"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-01-15", "value": "88.37"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-01-22", "value": "34.31"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-01-29", "value": "0.05"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-02-05", "value": "4.90"}, 
           {"name": "C", "date": "2017-02-12", "value": "6.15"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-01-08", "value": "5.55"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-01-15", "value": "8.37"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-01-22", "value": "4.31"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-01-29", "value": "50.05"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-02-05", "value": "4.90"}, 
           {"name": "D", "date": "2017-02-12", "value": "6.15"}
```

HTML:

```
                        <thead>

                            <tr id="row">

                                <th class="align-right"  *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected|slice:0:8">{{item.date}}</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>

                        <tbody id="body">

                            <tbody contenteditable='true'>

                            <tr  class="align-right">
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
                                    <td *ngIf="item.name == 'A'" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>  
                                           {{item.value}}
                                </td>
                                </ng-container>
                            </tr>
                            <tr  class="align-right">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
                                        <td *ngIf="item.name == 'B'" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>  
                                                {{item.value}}
                                    </td>
                                    </ng-container>
                            </tr>
                            <tr  class="align-right">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
                                        <td *ngIf="item.name == 'C'" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>  
                                                {{item.value}}
                                    </td>
                                    </ng-container>
                            </tr>
                              <tr  class="align-right">
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
                                        <td *ngIf="item.name == 'D'" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>  
                                                {{item.value}}
                                    </td>
                                    </ng-container>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
```

I do not want to hard-code the names: "A", "B", "C" and "D" in ngIf in HTML for the values to be displayed. Instead I want it to loop in the "name" field and display the value accordingly for that particular name.
I also do not want to change the json structure.

Please help.

Regards
Neha

Comment: And what is your question/error ?

Comment: You have to group by name, so have a json like [{name:"A",data:[{date: "2017-01-01", "value": "103.57"},{date: "2017-01-01", "value": "103.57"}..] and use two *ngFor

Comment: @trichetriche  there is no error. I just want to avoid hardcoding

Comment: Oh I see. Wait a minute please, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Eliseo Is there any other way apart from modifying the json structure?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

More efficient (only iterate the whole array once and then iterate just for each specific name rather then the whole array for each name):

In the html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
      <tr class="align-right">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of seperated[name]">
          <td [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>
            {{item.value}}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
</ng-container>
```

In the Component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initNames();
  }


  seperated = {};

  names = [];

  initNames() {
    this.calendarTableSelected.forEach(item => {
      if (!this.seperated[item.name]) {
        this.seperated[item.name] = [];
      }

      this.seperated[item.name].push(item);
    });

    this.names = Object.keys(this.seperated);
  }
```

**This is probably not be the most efficient way to do it**, but you can try save in another array only the items by distinct name (every name can only appear once) , then do something like this

```
      <tr class="align-right" *ngFor="let unique of distinctNames">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
          <td *ngIf="item.name == unique.name" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>
            {{item.value}}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
```

In the component :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initNames();
  }

  distinctNames = [];

  initNames() {
    let unique = this.calendarTableSelected.filter(this.onlyUnique);
    this.distinctNames = unique;
  }

  onlyUnique(item, index, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(arr.find(v => v.name == item.name)) === index;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data is returned and stored in the variable `data`.

First, create a variable called `names` :

```
names: string[] = [];
```

Then, on data received, populate your array :

```
this.names = this.data.filter(line => {
  if (!this.names.includes(line.name)) { this.names.push(line.name); }
});
```

In your HTML, you can now iterate over your array of names

```
<tr class="align-right" *ngFor="let name of names">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
    <td *ngIf="item.name == name" [(ngModel)]="item.value" ngDefaultControl>
      {{item.value}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```